# Unexpected result from ArcLength

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to determine the arc lenght of a parametric curve $C: \{x(t),y(t) \} = \{ \cos(t)^p , \sin(t)^p \}$ with $p$ between $0$ and $1$, and $t$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

I set up the following function of $p$:

```
L[p_] :=  ArcLength[{Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
                       Method -> {"NIntegrate", MaxRecursion -> 20}]
```

For $p=1$ we have a quarter of a circle of radius 1 and we know the arc length is equal to $\pi/2$. The above function gives the correct result: `1.5708`.

For $p$ close to zero, the curve approaches a square, and we know the result should be very close to $2$. However, the function doesn't even come close to it. Evaluating `L[1/100]` results in `1.30603`. Not close to `2` (it's not even bigger than `Pi/2`).

Plotting, results in the following:

`Plot[L[p], {p, 0, 1}]`

[image]

Any ideas? I'm running 11.0.0.0

Comment: I get a warning from `NIntegrate` ("Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity...") when trying to evaluate `L` for small `p`.

Comment: @MarcoB  I don't get any warnings when evaluating `L[1/100]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems to be a precision thing.

```
L[p_] = {Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p}

ArcLength[L[1/100], {t, 0, π/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000]

1.99447959240474567...
```

Answer (score 7):

I can only provide an alternative to bypass `ArcLength`.

The points `pts` of a quarter circle are scaled such that they lie on the desired curve; afterwards the length of the polygonal line is computed.

You will still get problems for values of `p` very close to `0`, but at least you may obtain a qualitatively correct plot (so I hope).

Certainly this method won't provide you with the best possible accuracy. The relative error between the arclength $\ell$ of an arc and the length $s$ of a secant is roughly $|\ell/s - 1\| \leq \ell^2 \, \max(|\kappa|)$ in the limit of $\ell \to 0$. Here $\kappa$ denotes the curvature of the curve. Since the maximal curvature of the curve goes to $\infty$ for $p \to \infty$, the quality of this approximation will reduce significantly for $p \to 0$.

```
n = 10000;
pts = Transpose[{Cos[Subdivide[0., Pi/2, n]], Sin[Subdivide[0., Pi/2, n]]}];
L[p_] := With[{x = pts/Power[Dot[(Abs[pts]^(1/p)), {1., 1.}], p]},
  Total[Sqrt[Dot[Differences[x]^2, {1., 1.}]]]
  ]
Plot[L[p], {p, 0.001, 1}]
```

[image]

## Edit

The ratio behind this is that in contrast to the parameterization

```
γ[t_, p_] = {Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p};
```

the parameterization

```
η[t_, p_] = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}/ Power[Cos[t]^(1/p) + Sin[t]^(1/p), p];
```

has finite speed which is always helpful for determining the arclength by integration:

```
assume = {p > 0, 0 < t < Pi/2};
speedγ[t_, p_] = Simplify[Sqrt[D[γ[t, p], t].D[γ[t, p], t]], assume];
speedη[t_, p_] = Simplify[Sqrt[D[η[t, p], t].D[η[t, p], t]], assume];
Quiet@GraphicsRow[{
   Plot[Evaluate[Table[speedγ[t, 2^-k], {k, 0, 10}]], {t, 0, Pi/2},
    PlotLabel -> "Speed of γ",
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}
    ],
   Plot[Evaluate[Table[speedη[t, 2^-k], {k, 0, 10}]], {t, 0, Pi/2},
    PlotLabel -> "Speed of η",
    PlotRange -> {0, 10}
    ]
   },
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

[image]

Whit this parameterization, one can also employ `NIntegrate` to compute the arclength, at least for not too small `p`.

```
NIntegrate[speedη[t, 1/1000], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
```

> 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p}, {t, 0, Pi/2}], {p, 0.01, 1}]
```

gives this plot at $p=0.01$:

(An unpreprocessing plot was here.)

**UPDATE:**

```
p = 0.01; ParametricPlot[{Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}]
```

[image]

So yes, the sides **are not** shrinking, but *Mathematica* seems to be missing some of the curve ...

**ADDITIONAL UPDATE:**

```
f[t_][p_] := {Cos[t]^p, Sin[t]^p};
p = 0.01;
k = 10^6;
Show[
  ListLinePlot[Transpose@f[\[Pi]/(2 k) Range[0, k]][p], PlotStyle -> Red], 
  ListPlot[Transpose@f[\[Pi]/(2 k) Range[0, k]][p], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False
]
```

If we sample $t$ with one million equally spaced points, there are big jumps to the first and the last point!

[image]

```
Plot[f[10^-q][.01][[2]], {q, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"-Log10[t]", "f[[2]]"}]
```

This plot shows that we need $t \le 10^{-100}$ for the $y$-value of the curve to be less than $\approx 0.1$ when $p=.01$.

[image]

Comment: >but the sides are shrinking. Not really. Check your plotrange

Comment: Yes, but this does not seem to answer the OP's question. Try including smaller values of $p$.

Comment: Yes, just doing that now!  But too late!  Already being dinged with the minus ones!!

Comment: @mjw Well, thank you for your enthusiasm, but next time don't rush it. If you so desperately need to make a contribution, post a comment.

Comment: No, not that desperate ... By the way, you guys are tough!  Imagine a classroom where a student gives an answer/suggestion that is not correct.  Or a collaboration with somebody making a mistake.  Seems that "Mathematica Stack Exchange" culture does not like people taking risks.  May hurt creativity ... But we will have strictly precise, quality answers!!

Comment: Oh, and is it possible to put images in the comments, btw?

Comment: @mjw "Seems that "Mathematica Stack Exchange" culture does not like people taking risks." To the contrary. I was really surprise that posts in this threads were downvoted so quickly. Downvotes on answers are actually _very_ uncommon on this site.

Comment: @mjw I wouldn't like this to become Quora. And I guess you have to link images in comments.

Comment: @mjw I've read your edit. `Mathematica seems to be missing some of the curve`  Interesting, but could that be an artifact from plotting?

Comment: @Henrik, Thank you.  I've been here less than a month, and I've actually up-voted a handful of other posts (not correct, but not necessarily objectionable) to bring them back up to zero.

Comment: @Ivan,  yes, point well taken!  Could be an artifact.  But why is the `ArcLength[]` returning wrong results?  Seems that in both cases *Mathematica* is undersampling ...

Comment: @mjw I get this when plotting for `p=0.01` https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyADy.png This is weird.

Comment: Yes, I think it has to do with the relative scaling of the change in $x$ and $y$ values as functions of $t$.  Near small $t$ there is a huge jump in $x$ for fixed $p$.  I don't have time now to investigate, but a guess is that it is a sampling issue.  Perhaps values are computed at fixed increments of $t$?

Comment: A downvote doesn't mean that you're a bad person, it means that someone somewhere didn't find your answer useful. It's an unremarkable, ordinary thing that can be allowed to pass without comment.